# Reverse vertical one of the subplots in python

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, subplot

I have two data frames to plot. One of bar chart, another one is a line chart.
I want to plot the barchart upside to down. (vertically reversed.)
How can i handle this?

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
tidy = results.melt(id_vars='Day').rename(columns=str.title)
ax1 = sns.lineplot(x='Day', y='Value', hue='Variable', data=tidy, ax=ax1)
tidy2 = drugs.melt(id_vars='Day').rename(columns=str.title)
ax1 = sns.barplot(x='Day', y='Value', hue='Variable', data=tidy2, ax=ax1)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
ax1.legend(loc=1)
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)
```

[image]

Comment: Create an inverted [twin axis](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/two_scales.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-two-scales-py) for your barplot

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried this one. "ax2.invert_yaxis()", it is worked